# Android: Open a Dialog by clicking on programatically added views into a RecyclerView

Tags: java, android, adapter

**What I have:** a button that when clicked adds a custom view (a button, a textView and an EditText) into a recyclerView. When the button inside some view gets clicked that view gets removed.

**What I want:** a button that when clicked adds a custom view (a button, a TextView and an EditText) into a RecyclerView. When a button inside some view gets clicked, a DialogFragment shows.

I guess I could do that inside the Adapter but that feels like it would mess up with the whole project architecture, so I need a way to do it in my activity class.

**MyAdapter.java**

```
public class MyAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<MyAdapter.ViewHolder> {

    private List<String> items = new ArrayList<>();

    public void addItem(String name) {
        items.add(name);
        notifyItemInserted(items.size() - 1);
    }

    public void removeItem(int position) {
        items.remove(position);
        notifyItemRemoved(position);
    }

    @Override
    public ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext());
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.grid_item_button, parent, false);

        return new ViewHolder(view);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(ViewHolder holder, int position) {
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return items.size();
    }


    static int i;

    class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder implements View.OnClickListener {

        private Button button;
        private TextView ClassName;
        private EditText EditName;

        public ViewHolder(View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
            ClassName = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.ClassName);
            button = (Button) itemView.findViewById(R.id.grid_button);
            EditName = (EditText) itemView.findViewById(R.id.editName);
            button.setOnClickListener(this);
            ClassName.setId(++i);
            EditName.requestFocus();

        }

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            removeItem(getAdapterPosition());
        }
    }

}
```

**Main activity's onCreate**

```
RecyclerView recyclerView = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.ClassesRecyclerView);
    assert recyclerView != null;
    recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new GridLayoutManager(this, 3));
    final MyAdapter adapter = new MyAdapter();
    recyclerView.addItemDecoration(new SampleItemDecoration());
    recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);
    recyclerView.setNestedScrollingEnabled(false);

    adapter.addItem("");

    findViewById(R.id.button_add).setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            adapter.addItem("");
        }
    });
```

Comment: Is there a reason you can't just add an item to the RecyclerView's adapter and refresh it ?

Comment: What do you mean exatly?

Comment: I'm not sure I understood your question correctly.  You just want to change what the button does? Or you want two different kinds of rows in the RecyclerView?

Comment: All the rows and the added views look the same, only with diffrent ID's. what I want is to open a DialogFragment when I click in one of those added views

Comment: Have you read this? http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2012/05/using-dialogfragments.html

Comment: Yes my problem is not to open a dialog, my problem is how to open a dialog by clicking in a button that's inside an Adapter, I've tried inflating the layout in wich the button is, but it doesn't work

Comment: From the button click you followed the instructions in the "Showing the Dialog" part of that guide, and it didn't work?  What happened?

Comment: Yes it didn't work

Comment: "Didn't work" meaning what?  Nothing happened?  There was an error in logcat?  The phone exploded?  How do you expect to get help without explaining the problem?

Comment: Nothing happened. I don't think you're understanding my issue >.< I know how to pop a Dialog fragment normally, the thing is, im trying to open it by clicking on a button that is in a layout I'm adding programmatically through an adapter. So I have two options: to open the dialog in the button listener INSIDE the adapter, or inside the main actiivty, I'd prefer in the activity for good architecture reasons, so I have to inflate the layout I'm addind right? That should work, but it doesn't (doesn't do anything when I click)